# Get Access Token Implicit Instagram Authentification

Tags: authentication, instagram, client-side

I'm trying to get access_token for my Instagram app(at the moment just empty container with configured settings, all valid), following this spec 
https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/
Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication -> Step One: Direct your user to our authorization URL -> 
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=**CLIENT-ID**&redirect_uri=**REDIRECT-URI**&response_type=token

As client_id I'm using my App ID client_id=App ID from there
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/**APP_ID**/dashboard/
, as a redirect_uri I'm using my wordpress site address. 
However instead of access_token there is a error message:
{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid platform app"}

What is the reason of such response, is it smth wrong with link parameters CLIENT-ID, REDIRECT-URI or I should post real app not just empty container for testing purposes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `client_id` which you are using is the Facebook App ID, but this is incorrect. There is a specific Instagram App ID that you should be using instead. From your App dashboard, on the left side menu, you'll want to find your Instagram App settings (likely by clicking on Instagram "Basic Display" if that is the kind of app you have set up).

[image: Facebook App dashboard]

From there, after your scroll down a bit on the right, you will see Instagram App ID along with your Instagram App Secret. This Instagram App ID is what you should be using in your authorization URL.